# Extract subset of object based on another object's values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, search

Say I have two objects, one containing the data and another containing values which are keys in the former object:

```
const obj = {
    'one': {},
    'two': {},
    'three': {},
    'four': {},
    'five': {},
};

const tstObj = {
    'someKey1': 'one',
    'someKey2': 'three',
    'someKey3': 'four'
};
```

I need to create another object containing elements with keys `tstObj` and corresponding values in `srcObj`. For the above example, this would be:

```
result = {
   'someKey1': {}, //one object
   'someKey2': {}, //three object
   'someKey3': {}, //four object
}
```

This is what I did:

```
const result = {};

Object.keys(tstObj).forEach(key => {
    if (srcObj[key]) {
        result[key] = srcObj[tstObj[key]]
    }
});
```

While the above would work for a simple and small object like in the example, I am not too happy with this solution for a large object which is deeply nested. Is there a better and more efficient way of achieving the same for a deeply nested object?

Comment: What do you mean by "deeply nested"? It's not very clear, can you give an example of such an input and the expected output?

Comment: `if (srcObj[key])` - this check seems to do nothing in given example. As for performance, each of those nested objects is actually a separate one; if what you do is just creating references, you should be safe from memory perspective.

Comment: By deeply nested to you mean that you need to extract deep property paths such as `some.deep.path`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The deeply nested object would have the same parent keys i.e. 'one', 'two', 'three'. Thinking about it closely, the deeply nested structure doesn't really matter in my question. It's more about it being a really large object.